# Launching the browser using SPLINTER throws error

Tags: python, python-3.x, splinter

Hi I have tried to run the code which is used to open a browser, enter URL and close the browser(https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) using SPLINTER in python. The sample code in the above URL is what I tried.

I got the following errors:

```
C:\Users\irgfff\Desktop>python browse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\irgfff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "C:\Users\irgfff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\subprocess
.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\irgfff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\subprocess
.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "browse.py", line 4, in <module>
with Browser() as browser:
File "C:\Users\irgfff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packa
ges\splinter\browser.py", line 63, in Browser
return driver(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\irgfff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packa
ges\splinter\driver\webdriver\firefox.py", line 48, in __init__
timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Users\irgfff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\irgfff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packa
ges\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' 
executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Could you let me know what I need to configure to avoid these errors ?

I am using Python 3.6.1
Firefox Version - 52
SPLINTER version 0.7.5

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. You must add PATH the location of geckodriver and webdriver.

You can download geckodriver(https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) here.

good luck